# Shell script for running subprocesses two at a time

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Let's assume there are a total of 10 subprocesses which I want my shell script to run. Subprocess (i.e. a process created within the shell script)  being called x1...10 for simplicity. A normal shell script would have 10 lines; let's assume each line calls ./xi. However, to maximize efficiency, I know my hardware allows for two of the subprocesses to be launched at the same time. Therefore, at any point in time, two of these processes should be running. The moment that one is done, the next is launched. No order should be assumed in how they finish, any order is fine as they are assumed independent. Is there an elegant way of doing this in a shell script? Note, each x1...x10 should run once only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seq 10 | xargs -P2 -I{} ./xi
```

- `seq 10` - Outputs 10 numbers. We don't care about them.
- `xargs` run a command for each input

  - `-P2` runs two processes at a time.
  - `-I{}` replaces each `{}` in the command for the input line. So just discard the input.
  - `./x{}` run this command for each line in the input.

Final answer: `cat myshellscript.sh | xargs -L 1 -I CMD -P 2 bash -c CMD`

With `myshellscript.sh` being a file like this:

```
./task-jsuqh
./task-siuww
./task-uqywh
./task-sdqaw
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this only runs each of the xi twice. What I want is something like start with x1,x2 -- x2 finished start x3 - x3 finished start x4 - x1 finished start x5 ...

Comment: so you want `./x{}`? Use `xargs -t` to debug `xargs`

Comment: Correct for numbered of course. I will add this to your answer (for cases where scripts are written in the sh file and not ordered), and accept it: cat myshellscript.sh | xargs -L 1 -I CMD -P 2 bash -c CMD